# Why do I get Permision Denied?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

```
from ipaddress import *
from socket import *
x = str(IPv4Address('125.67.8.0'))
s = socket()
s.bind((x,456))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

even after calling the ipaddress constructor to construct a new ip address, why can't I not bind? I ran the program on superuser mode, what is wrong with my method?

Comment: Is the address `125.67.8.0` on the machine you're running this as?  Are you running as a privileged user to use a port below 1024?

Comment: Besides the above, just a curiousity of mine, why are you stringifying an object which youve just created out of a string?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the bind command, the parameter for the IP is a string, so a simple `s.bind(('125.67.8.0', 456))`will work. You don't have to take the IP, as a string, and perform operations on it to turn it back into a string.